# Valid JSON using Python

Tags: python, json

Is this a valid JSON object?

```
{"Age": "2", "Name": "Rice, Master. Eugene", "Parch": "1", "Pclass": "3", "Ticket": "382652", "PassengerId": "17", "SibSp": "4", "Embarked": "Q", "Fare": "29.125", "Survived": "0", "Cabin": "", "Sex": "male"}
```

Do I need an EOF?

I have used the following to create the file:

```
import json
import sys
fieldnames=["PassengerId","Survived","Pclass","Name","Sex","Age","SibSp","Parch","Ticket","Fare","Cabin","Embarked"]
csvfile=open('t1.csv','r')
jsonfile = open('file1.json', 'w')
reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile, fieldnames)
for row in reader:
#       if reader.line_num ==1:
                #continue # Skip the first line
        json.dump(row, jsonfile)
        jsonfile.write('\n')
print("Total No of Lines Wriiten : "+ str(reader.line_num))
```

Comment: Yes, that is JSON. You can test it by opening the dev tools in your browser (ctrl+shift+j in chrome) and typing `JSON.parse('...')` in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Simple test via [json.loads()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
import json

j = json.loads('{"Age": "2", "Sex": "male"}')
print j
```

or alternatively test it by loading it directly from the saved file using [json.load()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load):

```
import json

with open('file1.json', 'r') as f:
    j = json.load(f)
    print j
```

... seems to be valid.